# Audit sessions to Dynamics CRM 4

Tags: active-directory, dynamics-crm, audit-trail

I'm looking for information about how to audit logins to Dynamics CRM 4. This is an on premise site, and use Active Directory for authentication.
I'm currently evaluating two choices:

1- Create a custom http handler and create a handler for begin_session event of HttpApplication class

2- Use a system policy to audit credential validation in Windows.

Is there any other choice? If there's not, which one of this is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally these two solutions are suggested:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2009/04/08/crm-usage-reporting-unleashed.aspx

http://bproud2banindian.blogspot.com/2010/09/login-log-out-informations-for-users-in.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know that modifying web.config of Dynamics CRM app isn't a supported scenario. This is why IIS log parsing is preferred?

Comment: yes, consider also that CRM 4.0 is nearly to be not supported anymore by Microsoft.

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm considering modifying the web.config, as this deployment won't survive much longer :-) Thanks for your time!